# How does XLockDisplay() work across multiple processes?

Tags: x11, xlib

I'm dealing with multiple processes that read eachothers's drawables and thus need synchronization. [`XLockDisplay`](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/display/XLockDisplay.html) is supposed to "lock out all other threads" from using the display, but does that apply across multiple processes?

Also, do all processes need to call `XInitThreads` or just the one(s) calling `XLockDisplay`?

Comment: No it does not work across processes. Why would you ever assume so? I don't see any hint of such possibility in the documentation.

Comment: @n.m. ...because for what I know unix makes little distinction between processes and threads. maybe X spec makes no distinction at all since the term "process" is nowhere to be found, making it implicit. Or maybe the semaphore is in the X server itself rather than in my processes. Curious: How do you know it does not work?

Comment: No, your impression about threads and processes is wrong. User code sees them completely differently. Besides, different clients may well run on different machines, Unix,Windows, on the other side of the planet, whatever. *The only reliable communication channel between them is the X server itself*. Anyway, when you call `exit()`, all threads terminate, do you also conclude that all processes terminate?

Answer (score 1):

XLockDisplay func (and LockDisplay macros) has to be used inside the same XClient app,  ie process... They make no sense btw XClients (so btw 2 processes). This is a way to protect against multiple threads (so inside the same process) attempting to access the same X connection (eg see GLX-1.4, ch. 2.7)

In order to read the whole content (buffer) of another window, you could take a look at any app that makes a screenshot from your desktop or from a single window (see 'scrot' source code for example).

If you want to exchange data btw XClients, use their Properties/Atoms (see XLib ICCC).

Comment: reading buffer other process's window (merging multiple really) is actually the end game. good idea to look at some screenshot code as it probably deals with the same issue.